# Working example of IFTTT recipe with RSS capability

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that

Could any [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) users share working examples of their recipes involving RSS feeds, or critique my recipe? I signed up today and created a basic script to push NYTimes articles to a Dropbox folder, but I fear my implementation was flawed as it has not yet been triggered.

My attempt: https://ifttt.com/recipes/72896

Comment: you can check the recipe logs from https://ifttt.com/myrecipes/personal/72896/logs

Answer (score 4):

**[Further updates to this answer added below the original answer on 4th January 2013]**
If all you're looking to do is push new articles to dropbox, you could base your recipe on this one: https://ifttt.com/recipes/59335

From your recipe it looks like you're trying to append each new article to a text file but that you're also trying to create a new file title based on each article title. This is why I'm not 100% certain the recipe above is what you're looking for but if you want a new file for each article, the recipe above should work well.

Let us know if not!

**[Updates to Original answer made based on poster's comments]**
It looks like the reason that the recipe above wouldn't work for you is because the NY Times is pushing out text-based content and there's nothing to download - I tried it to double check and got the same result.

I then created two variations on getting the trigger (a new article in the RSS feed) to save to a text file in Dropbox and both seem to have worked - I've added screenshots of the make-up of the recipes below. Note that they come out with all the HTML tags (or did when I tried this!) but I'm assuming this is what you were expecting. I've used the blog Apartment Therapy in the example below just because their blog posts are so frequent that they worked well for testing :)

[image: Example 1]

Or

[image: Example 2]

If you still can't get your recipe to work, I would suggest trying the Apartment Therapy feed (http://feeds.apartmenttherapy.com/apartmenttherapy/main) just as a test to see if the problem is actually the interaction with NY Times feed. That might be the easiest way to isolate the problem.

Comment: You are correct- I was indeed attempting to create a text file that would append new entries to itself. In fact, I originally used the recipe you provided, but couldn't get it to work either so I built my own. I was hoping that someone might have a working example and could correct whatever was causing the problem.

Comment: Hey @nitrl, I tried a couple of things out in my own account based on your clarification above and they seemed to work - I added screenshots above. As I mentioned, I would actually start by changing the feed to something else just to see if that's not your major issue. Hope this helps!